# When hand-coding CodedUI Tests, is there a way to clear text inputs before populating them?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

My goal is to clear text inputs before populating them.

For example, I am populating form fields using:

`Keyboard.SendKeys(myInput, "Some Text");`

My form populates fields on page load using cookie values.

When I try to use CodedUI to populate the email field, it appends a string to the current value instead of adding the desired value only.

My goal is to use CodedUI to populate the email field with:

- foo@bar.com

But, since the field is already aaa@bbb.com (populated with cookie data on page load), it ends up being:

- aaa@bbb.comfoo@bar.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked. Set the text property before sending keys:

```
myInput.Text = "";
Keyboard.SendKeys(myInput, "Some Text");
```

Comment: Lol, I also wanted to suggest this, but it seemed so obvious :) I mostly use .Text = to set the values. Why use SendKeys, its much slower. I use SendKeys only if the input field has events triggered on the actual typing of the user as inline validation for example.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to double click the field to select all text, when the text is selected it will be overwritten.

```
Mouse.DoubleClick(myInput)
```

Maybe better is to clear the cookies before each test run

```
BrowserWindow.ClearCookies()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following with success:

```
control.SetFocus();
Keyboard.SendKeys("a", System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.Control);
Keyboard.SendKeys("{Delete}");
Keyboard.SendKeys(control, value);
```